# como resolver erro de permissão na chave publica do Git dentro do VSCODE

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

O meu vscode não permite trocar dados entre o Git e o Github (push, pull e sync), e isso só acontece quando uso as ferramentas do vscode (quando abro a barra de pesquisa "ctrl shift p", ou quando aperto no ícone de sincronização), retornando um erro na chave publica, sendo que funciona normalmente no terminal integrado ou no terminal do git:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, como dito, funciona perfeitamente no terminal, pois, já configurei e usei muito meu git:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Sua chave SSH possui senha e isso [não é suportado](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/13680) pelo Visual Studio Code (e na [grande maioria](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/13680#issuecomment-526786635) dos outros editores também não, inclusive os da JetBrains).

Uma possível solução é gerar novas chaves SSH sem senha e adicionar à sua conta do GitHub.

Se isso não for opção, tente usar a [autenticação HTTPS ao invés de SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041729/why-does-github-recommend-https-over-ssh). Você pode fazer isso atualizando o endereço do [remoto](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Git-Essencial-Trabalhando-com-Remotos):

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USUÁRIO/REPOSITÓRIO.git
```